# Facebook login.php doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I use this Facebook login URL:
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2F

But after login, it redirects to facebook.com.

At Facebook developers I setup website platform and app domains input to mydomain.com.

Please help!

Best regards,
Feco

Comment: Please don't vote down, write something.. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I was use bad syntax.
This is working:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
  client_id={app-id}
  &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
```

Best regards,
Feco